# Split a string with several parameters

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have file with a lot of string like :

```
V004_2aB181500181559aB182000191659
```

or

```
V001_2a194300194359a203100203159
```

Each letter represent a member and after it's attendance hours.

That means in the 1st line the Member a and B were present from `[18h15min00sec - 18h15min59sec]` and also from `[18h20min00sec - 19h16min59sec]` ...

I would like to create an array where I summarize all the attendance for example :

```
table = [Member,Start_hour,End_Hour]
```

Comment: Is aB in `V004_2aB181500181559aB182000191659` one member or two?

Comment: They represent 2 members

Comment: Is `V` a member? what's the part of `V004_2`? It's not clear. And how do you explain the second example?

Comment: No it's not a member you can delete this part 
It could start like this aB181500181559aB182000191659

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input see if following works.

I am assuming fields are static , we can get rid of anything before underscore and first occurrence of alphanumeric characters. As well as one string contains data for one user.

**Demo Code [ Updated ]**

```
import re

def mySplit(s):
    #Filter first part
    thisStr = s.rsplit('_2', 1)[1]

    #To split the string at digits you can use re.split with the regular expression \d+:
    return filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+)', thisStr))


def prepMemberData(aList):
    memData = []
    keys = []
    values = []

    for item in aList:
        #print item

        if item.isalpha():
            keys += item

        if item.isdigit():
            hr1,mi1,se1,hr2,mi2,se2 = re.findall(r'.{1,2}',item,re.DOTALL)
            values.append(hr1 + "h" + mi1 + "m" + se1 + "s" + "," + hr2 + "h" + mi2 + "m" + se2 + "s")

    temp = []
    if len(keys) != len(values):
        for i in values:
            temp += i , i
            values = temp

    myLst = [(x ,y) for x, y in zip(keys, values)] #Merge key and value lists

    for i in myLst:        
        #Remove ' () [] 
        newi = re.sub(r'[\'|(|)|[|\]]',r'',str(i))
        memData.append(newi)

    return memData


#Process first String
myStr = "V004_2aB181500181559aB182000191659"
myLst1= mySplit(myStr)
print prepMemberData(myLst1)

#Process second String
myStr2 = "V001_2a194300194359a203100203159"
myLst2= mySplit(myStr2)
print prepMemberData(myLst2)
```

**OutPut [ Updated ]**

```
    Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
['a, 18h15m00s,18h15m59s', 'B, 18h15m00s,18h15m59s', 'a, 18h20m00s,19h16m59s', 'B, 18h20m00s,19h16m59s']
['a, 19h43m00s,19h43m59s', 'a, 20h31m00s,20h31m59s']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: If answer satisfies your requirement, please accept the answer so that it doesn't show up as unanswered and this closes Q/A loop also.

Comment: it's not exactly what I require, I would rather something like : 
mem1Data =  ['a', '18h15m00s', '18h15m59s', 'B','18h15m00s', '18h15m59s','a','18h20m00s', '19h16m59s','B','18h20m00s', '19h16m59s']
like also split up the letter

Comment: OK, I guess I didn't read earlier comments that aB are two members. Anyway, I updated code (see updates above) and tried to match output  (see updates above) close to what you need. Let me if this works.